# How to put in Jquery file while using Cloud9 IDE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cloud9-ide

I am using cloud9 ide for my JavaScript project. I tried a lot but I was really unable to add the JQuery file into my project. The only Idea I had was copying the file content and pasting it into a new file that is created on Cloud9 IDE. Is there a solution to import JavaScript files so as to easily include these things into my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drag and drop the jQuery file into the file tree on Cloud9.

Answer (score 0):

Grab a fork on Github:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery

log into your Cloud9 account and find the fork amongst your github projects (assuming you've connected Github to your account)